# Java List filter by date

Tags: java, javafx, collections, filter, java-stream

I try use my first filter in [`FilteredList`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/javafx/collections/transformation/FilteredList.html) but of course it doesn't work.

```
public class ListRemove {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        ObservableList<CashBalance> cashBalanceList = FXCollections.observableArrayList();

        LocalDate f1 = LocalDate.of(2011, Month.JANUARY, 1);
        LocalDate f2 = LocalDate.of(2015, Month.AUGUST, 2);

        CashBalance c1 = new CashBalance();
        CashBalance c2 = new CashBalance();
        c1.setData(f1);
        c2.setData(f2);

        cashBalanceList.setAll(c1, c2);

        FilteredList<CashBalance> filteredList = new FilteredList<CashBalance>(cashBalanceList);

        filteredList.stream().filter(p -> p.getData().isAfter(LocalDate.of(2012, Month.JUNE, 2)))
                .collect(Collectors.toList());

        for (CashBalance l : filteredList) {

            System.out.println(l.getData());

        }
    }
}
```

Should show one date but two are displayed. What am I doing wrong ?

Comment: And `CashBalance` looks like?

Comment: `filteredList.removeIf(…)`? Seems to me to be a little bit simpler than using a stream.

Comment: of course, but I'm learning filters and streams :)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Your approach does not filter the list, but copies the elements to a new list, with some elements filtered out.  This leaves the original unchanged.  You need to assign this new list to a variable to make use of it.

However, you are using the `FilteredList` class, which provides a filtered view of another list.  You can set the filter predicate using the `setPredicate` method

```
filteredList.setPredicate(p -> p.getData().isAfter(LocalDate.of(2012, Month.JUNE, 2)));
```

Or in the constructor as the second parameter

```
 FilteredList<CashBalance> filteredList = new FilteredList<CashBalance>(cashBalanceList, p -> p.getData().isAfter(LocalDate.of(2012, Month.JUNE, 2)));
```

Answer (score 1):

change to:

```
filteredList = 
    filteredList
     .stream()
     .filter(
               p -> p.getData().isAfter(LocalDate.of(2012, Month.JUNE, 2))
    ).collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Comment: It should be noted that this requires changing the type of `filteredList` to `List` though...